# vim - how to display a man page in a new window?

Tags: vim

`K` displays the man page of current word in a new window.

However, `:Map <page>` displays it in a horizontal split (after adding `runtime! ftplugin/man.vim` to `.vimrc`).

How can I set vim to open the man page in a new window?

I know I can minimize the split by hitting `Ctrl-w _`, but is there a way to open it in a new window from the beginning?

Comment: A new window? I think there's some confusion in terminology here. The horizontal split is a window in Vim's terms. Do you mean `:Man ...` should run an external command like `K` does?

Comment: Yes. I mean how to make it behave like `K`?

Comment: If you're interested in customising Vim, checkout the sister site [vi.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own command instead of loading `ftplugin/man.vim`:

```
:command! -nargs=+ Man !man <args>
```

This defines a command `Man` which takes one or more arguments (`-nargs=+`) and calls `!man` with those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is in the ftplugin help:

```html
To use a vertical split instead of horizontal: >
        let g:ft_man_open_mode = 'vert'
```

Comment: You can also use **`vertical`** before a command to change the split orientation for just that command.